# How will std::spanstream usually be used in C++?

Tags: c++, strstream, c++23

`<spanstream>` will debut in C++23 (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23)).  According to the [proposal](https://wg21.link/p0448R4), they are string-streams with `std::span` based buffers.

My questions are:

- Does `std::spanstream` have somewhat equivalent uses of the old `std::strstream` (or [`strstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream) deprecated in C++ 98)?
- What will be the benefits of using them after the full release of C++ 23?

Comment: std::strstream? What is it? I would say it is a stream adapter to any sequenced data, like std::istringstream is a stream adapter to std::string with an advantage of not coping strings.

Comment: There have never been a `std::strstream` but I guess you mean the old pre-standard (and therefore not in any namespace) `strstream`?

Comment: ... I imagine with spanstream, it can finally be removed after more than 20 years of deprecation

Comment: @DesmondGold Thanks for the link. It's weird to see that in the actual standard library, and that it has only bee deprecated and not removed yet. IMO it shouldn't be in there at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Why shouldn't it be there? It's useful to be able to stream into/outof existing buffers, and `strstream` is the only way to do that.

Comment: From skimming [the paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0448r4.pdf) it looks like it is intended to offer the same thing `std::stringstream` does, but instead of having a `string` object you can't manage, `std::spanstream` will use a `span`(buffer) that you give it for the stream contents.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are intended to be a [near drop-in replacement](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0448r4.pdf) for `strstream` (except with proper bounds checking). As such, they will have the exact same use cases. When you have an existing buffer that you want to stream into/outof.

The ability to move a `std::string` into `stringstream`s added in C++20 eliminated the use case when the existing buffer is in a `std::string`. But sometimes you just have a naked `char const*` with a known length.

Comment: And how is it different from [std::format_to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_to)?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili it's a stream, not an iterator. Sometimes you have code that was written expecting to be `cout`ed (or `cin`ed)

Comment: @Caleth `std::format` falls back to `operator<<`, right? I don't see how the same buffer cannot be used with `format_to`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: You mean besides proper bounds checking? Also, doesn't the `operator<<` fallback have to allocate memory for the stream to write into? Effectively creating a `stringstream`, then copying from that into the output iterator?

Comment: @Nicol we have `format_to_n` for bounds checking.

Comment: I am not familiar with the fallback API tbh, but moving forward code should be written for the "format" API, right? I am confused if we are trying to deprecate the iostreams, or encourage them.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: "*I am confused if we are trying to deprecate the iostreams, or encourage them.*" Why does it have to be either/or? Also, `format` only works for outputting; it does nothing for inputting.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, adding duplicate functionality is hardly useful. The part of the standard library that I dread the most is iostreams, so I might be a bit biased. I would hope the next step would be adding a format-like API for input/file-handling.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `std::format` doesn't have an `operator<<` fallback.

Comment: @T.C. [here](https://youtu.be/ptba_AqFYCM?t=2043) fmt author mentioned that fmt falls back to `operator<<`, so I was recalling that. Perhaps it didn't make its way to C++20, or maybe they removed it down the road. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: fmt does, but the std one doesn't (this sort of fallback is an ODR-violation magnet)

Comment: @T.C. what do you mean by "ODR-violation management"? Would it be an ODR violation for `std::format` to fallback on `operator<<`?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: He said "magnet." As in, it attracts ODR violations, because in one place of the code, your `format` call could call `operator<<`, while in another place, it'd call your proper overload.

Comment: A prominent use case for `strstream` was that it could act over an existing buffer or create a dynamically growing one. The latter behavior is triggered by the default ctor while the former by constructing an `strstream` using an existing buffer. Can `std::spanstream` do this? All its constructors expect an existing buffer and span buffers are fixed (not dynamically growing). Given this restriction I'd call it a "nowhere near replacement"

Comment: @LorahAttkins: If you're dynamically allocating memory, you use a `stringstream`. There is no point to using `strstream` for that. You can move into and outof `stringstream`, so there isn't even an allocation savings.

Comment: @NicolBolas There's cases where `stringstream` is [inadequate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/933f1985-82cd-48f1-a198-2277523c212a/stdstringstreamltchar8gt-does-not-work-properly-if-the-stream-size-is-more-than-4gb?forum=vclanguage) and has been a pain in Windows for years. Features of `spanstream` are way more restricted compared to `strstream`; `strstream` was created with two modes in mind, dynamic and fixed and `spanstream` is no replacement for that. That said, the added safety is appreciated.

Comment: @LorahAttkins: "*There's cases where stringstream is inadequate*" No, that's a case where *certain implementations* of the type are not adequate to the user's needs. The standard does not *require* that any stream be able to support any particular data size. Microsoft's implementation of `strstream` could have been just as deficient as their implementation of `stringstream`. The fact that it wasn't isn't a problem that the C++ standard needs to solve. `stringstream` is the choice for when you need "dynamic" streams. If your implementation is insufficient, take it up with them.

Comment: @NicolBolas My argument is that `spanstream` is not a drop in replacement since `strstream` was designed with the aforementioned "dual" mode in mind and `spanstream` has nothing to do with this. Peter mentions it in the proposal: [A combination of external-fixed and internal-growing buffer allocation that strstreambuf provides is IMHO a doomed approach and very hard to use right.](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0448r4.pdf). It's less misleading to call it a "departure from that design" since that is what the introduction of spanstream signifies.