# Can an strstream directly use the buffer of a standard string

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream

Given that [strstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream) has the following constructor:

```cpp
strstream( char* s, int n, std::ios_base::openmode mode);
```

I was wondering whether I can use the buffer underlying a standard string directly, in "read-only" mode of course to avoid weird side-effects from buffer reallocation:

```cpp
std::string buffer("Dummy Data");
std::strstream ss(
  const_cast<char *>(buffer.data()), buffer.length(), std::ios_base::in);

std::string other;
ss >> other;
std::cout << other << std::endl;
```

To my surprise, the code above ends up making `other` an empty string. In the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream/strstream) there is an example where a C-array is used as a **static buffer** for `strstream`, so I'm wondering what's the reason it cannot use the contents of the `std::string` buffer?

Note: I can't use `std::stringstream` because the platform in question has a VS implementation that is limited to 4GB size as discussed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/933f1985-82cd-48f1-a198-2277523c212a/stdstringstreamltchar8gt-does-not-work-properly-if-the-stream-size-is-more-than-4gb?forum=vclanguage)

---

UPDATE:

I see that using `std::ios_base::app` (as in the example) pretty much makes my code work. The biggest problem now (according to the comments I'm getting) is that `strstream` is long deprecated. Maybe there's something in [boost iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) that could help but idk much about that library.

Comment: With file sizes like that I'd start looking into memory mapping the file and read from those.  There are platform indepenent libraries for that.

Comment: `strstream` was deprecated 25 years ago, you really shouldn't be using it

Comment: @AlanBirtles Is there another alternative to `std::stringstream` ? The code I'm working with uses streams to serialize data (e.g. `myStream << delimiter << current_data[i] << ...`) and then flushes those streams to disk. The content is already "in memory" so I can't see how the suggestion to memory map a file would work for me, unless I use that (the memory mapped file) as my buffer and check if similar syntax exists (I mean similar to `stream << content`)

Comment: This is explicitly marked as C++11, but just for completeness: C++23 std::spanstream is what you would want to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924325/how-will-stdspanstream-usually-be-used-in-c

Comment: @LorahAttkins Not entirely following your requirements, but why not write your own `std::streambuf` derived class. Then it can do whatever you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using [`strstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream) that was deprecated in C++98, and given that you can't use its standard recommended replacement which is [`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) due to the mentioned 4GB limitation in your compiler, you can use Boost's [`bufferstream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html#interprocess.streams.bufferstream) as an alternative like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7dPEajasa):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/streams/bufferstream.hpp>

namespace bi = boost::interprocess;

int main()
{
    std::string buffer("Dummy Data");

    bi::bufferstream ss(&buffer[0], buffer.size());

    std::string other;
    ss >> other;
    std::cout << other << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This class seems to be header only, so no need to compile boost. In any case, if using Visual Studio, you can use [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io) to easily install boost.

NOTE: As mentioned in Peppin's comment on the question, if your data originates from a file, it would be a better approach instead of reading it entirely into memory to just use memory-mapped files. There is a great example of how this is done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26265087/2059689) answer.

Comment: That's a great answer because the library also contains cross platform utilities for file mapping, which according to one of the comments should be an available fallback for really large datasets

Comment: @LorahAttkins yep, that comment is extremely right. If your data comes from a file, no point in reading it entirely to RAM. I just tried answering your question in the narrow sense. But I can provide answer with file mapping as well if you like.

Comment: Went into a rabbit-hole with this because I ignored `bufferstream` only works with static buffers yet allows using `operator<<` to populate a default constructed instance, i.e. one without a buffer (causing UB). Ended up using `vectorstream` for streams populated on the fly and `bufferstream` to "avoid copying existing buffers. Btw I reinstated the c++11 tag, because that is the language standard I'm targeting. If I had no standard requirement I could use `std::spanstream` which brings no extra dependencies.